# Lock Appeal Request April 2023 Promise Not to Change the Airlines

Tags: support, moderation

I am requesting for a lock appeal at [Is English the official language for international flights?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/179249/is-english-the-official-language-for-international-flights?).

The comment:

> This question is locked for now as OP keeps changing the airlines, which may make already given answers lose validity.

After two days, I am requesting the question to be unlocked for the following reasons:

> I have made a promise not to keep changing the airlines.

> I want to set a bounty and comment on the question and answers in the future.

UPDATE: Per Willeke below, I do not have any real change that I want to make. However, I have promised not to change the airlines anymore. Once I learn a lesson, the question can  be permanently unlocked. I asked [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/14286/what-were-the-original-latin-verbs-for-the-spanish-verbs) back in 2020 and despite making several edits there, that question has never been locked, but I still must remember not make any useless edits.

Update: It has been more than six months now. I think the question should now be unlocked. I have made a promise not to make useless changes to the question.

Comment: And yet you give no more reason for it to be unlocked six months on, when the causes of the locking continue to apply. The mere passage of time does not change this.

Comment: @Nij "the causes of the locking continue to apply" Where does it continue to apply?

Comment: It is notable that you don't see this, as it suggests the reasons given by Willeke have not been understood. Read their comments. Your belief that it's just a matter of time and votes and that you can merely say it's now fine is incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a real change you want to make which does not include changing the airlines I am happy to temporary unlock it for you, only for the one real change.

You have been warned twice that changes of the airlines named was not acceptable, but that has been the changes you kept making.

It does not matter that the current answers do not name airlines, your changes did go so wild that they might have invalidated the answers. Small changes are acceptable but not changes to the main topic of the question and that is what you did by changing the airlines.

Comment: I promise I will not keep changing the airlines or at least I will just remove all the airlines and keep just one.

Comment: There is no need, really no reason, to change anything about the airlines. Leave it as it is.

Comment: But anyway, I believe it should be unlocked now, but I will not change anything about the airlines.

Comment: I still see no reason to unlock other than you being unhappy about it being locked. You do not give good reasons, you do not tell what you want to change and I see no need to change anything in a question with several answers (and no recent activity other than by you.)

Comment: The reason why it should be unlocked is because I promise I will not keep changing the airlines.

Comment: Having checked your edit history, your question will never get unlocked as you have two deleted questions which have no resemblance to the original questions at all. Even deleted questions should not be edited beyond recognition.

Comment: "Having checked your edit history, your question will never get unlocked as you have two deleted questions which have no resemblance to the original questions at all." Sorry for that. I can break the stick and wait for a while. If I ask more questions in the future without any useless edits, only then I can get better chances.

Comment: Also, my question has a score of 5. It is unlikely that the question will remain locked.