# Request to appeal the lock on Travel Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, terminology

I have initially posted that [here](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8496/lock-appeal-request-april-2023-promise-not-to-change-the-airlines). After a long time, I have decided to request for the appeal here because I have promised not to make useless changes to questions.

I am requesting for the unlock not for me to add more airlines to the list, but to allow more users to vote and comment on the question and the answers in the future.

Comment: You have to react on the site involved as all the moderators and sometimes the regular users can act. And as it is not a travel question it has to go to the meta site to the travel site. I move it there for you.

Comment: I have asked the other mods to have a look as I am not impartial.

Comment: 24 April, 2023: *"However, I have promised not to change the airlines anymore."*  18 January, 2024: *"I ... want to remove all the airlines from the list and just keep one."* Do you see why people cannot believe your 'promise' now?

Comment: @Nij What I am saying is that just one airline in the list will be my final consideration. After that, I will not make further changes to the airlines.

Comment: This was a question from nearly a year ago? Talk about a hill to die on. Move on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with the lock imposed on that question and will not remove it. Further appeals will not change the outcome - whether on this site or others. Please move on - you're more than welcome to ask other questions on Travel.SE.

Comment: That is not fair. When I promise something, then my promise should be taken into account.

Comment: @Arunabh -The only reason to remove a lock is to make changes, and as we do not want any further changes to that post, the lock remains. No matter what your promise is.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I have asked so many questions on Stack Exchange, and they are usually not locked, and neither do I keep making changes to those questions.

Comment: That's good to hear, because otherwise they'd probably end up being locked as well. You still have not explained why you want this one unlocked.

Comment: @RoryAlsop The only reason why I want this unlocked is to allow more people to comment and vote in the future. Moreover, I currently have five airlines in the list. Today, I realize that five airlines in the list is too much. Willeke has warned me earlier not to keep adding more airlines to the list, but I one day, I try to add just one airline to the list, causing Willeke to lock the question. I really regret the edits I have made which have caused the lock, and so want to remove all the airlines from the list and just keep one.

Comment: @RoryAlsop And see https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/37608/how-are-languages-classified-into-families. There also, I have similar warnings not to bump the question to make useless edits. And I do not edit that question anymore.

Comment: As pointed out, the outcome is not going to change, and your reasoning here definitely doesn't sway that judgement. The fact you have had various warnings on various sites concerns me a lot - we aren't interested in your promise, but your actions. You know how to behave, now please do behave in future.